# I'm having trouble with css that's interferring with elements that I don't want it to

Tags: html, css

Here is my website.
http://www.gtaresources.net/

The css  makes anchor elements have certain css properties and i just want it for like a navigation bar. just the login button and when i add a menu. But for now you can see that green behind the image at the top right. It's not supposed to go behind every anchor i just want it for certain ones and i can't or don't know how to do inline css for only the menu with the a:visited and a:hover and stuff. What's the solution? I just need to make some of the css only work for a certain elements or elements.

I made notes of where the css that is interferring begins and ends.

Here my source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 

<html>
<head>
<title>GTA Resources</title>
<style type="text/css">
html
{
background-color: #003300;
padding-right: 11%;
padding-left: 11%;
}
body
{
background-color: black;
}
#p
{
color: white;
}
#para
{
color: white;
padding-right: 2%;
padding-left: 2%;
}
a
{
color: #003300;
}
.logo
{
padding-top: 4px;
padding-left: 4px;
}

ul {                  <!-- Css that is interferring begins -->
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

li {
float: left;
}

a:link, a:visited {
display: block;
width: 120px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #98bf21;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;


a:hover, a:active {
background-color: #7A991A;
}                         <!-- Css that is interferring ends -->
</style>
<script type = "text/javascript">

function validate() {
var un = document.myform.username.value;
var pw = document.myform.pword.value;
var valid = false;

var unArray = ["admin"];
var pwArray = ["password"];

for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
valid = true;
break;
}
}

if (valid) {
alert ("Logged In.");
window.location = "/victoria/logged_in.html";
return false;
}

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul background="/victoria/cutiepie2.jpg" hidden>
<li><a href="/scripts/call.php" id="blue">Call</a></li>
<li><a href="/scripts/text.html" id="blue">Text</a></li>
<li><a href="/menu/home.html" id="blue">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/menu/news.html" id="blue">News</a></li>
<li><a href="/menu/media.html" id="blue">Media</a></li>
<li><a href="/menu/downloads.html" id="blue">Downloads</a></li>
<li><a href="/menu/forum.html" id="blue">Forum</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="/index.html"><img src="/victoria/logo.jpg" width="250" height="75" class="logo"></a>

<ul style="list-style-type: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow: hidden;position: absolute;top: 4px;right: 4px;">
<li style="float: left;"><a style="display: block;width: 120px;font-weight: bold;color: #FFFFFF;background-color: black;text-align: center;padding: 4px;text-        decoration: none;text-transform: uppercase;" href="/victoria/logged_in.html">Log in</a></li>
</ul>

<form name = "myform" style="position: absolute; top: 0;right: 0;" hidden>

<p id="p">Username: <input type="text" name="username">

Password: <input type="password" name="pword">

<input type="button" value="log in" onclick= "validate()"></p>

</form>

<center><h1 style="color: #003300;">GTA Resources</h1></center>

<center><img src="http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/Call-of-Duty-Ghosts-Publisher-Wants-to-Break-GTA-5-Sales-Record-Soon-392209-2.jpg" 

width="1000" height="500"></center>

<br><br>

<p id="para">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Welcome to Gta Resources. This is a site all about gta, the cheats, mods, and videos of within it.  From hiliarous videos to
videos of how to make, convert, and import mods into gta. This site has everything. Right now it focuses on Gta 5 but in the future it will have topics on all 
the other Gta's too. This site will have media on the Mods for example, details in a description, videos on and how to do them, and download links, unless 
there is no link. Then I will try my best to give information on it, and where you might be able to get it. There will be a forum soon for discussing topics 
on anything Gta related. And just have a good time. Enjoi!!:)
</p>

<center><a href="/victoria/click_here_for_help.html">Click here for help</a></center>

<p id="p" style="text-align: right;">GTA Resources(c) 2014</p>

</body>
<!--MTD(c) 2014-->
</html>
```

Comment: Is your website down right now? It's not loading. Could you provide the actual code in your question?

Comment: Yeah i tried but it was asking me to format so i did but it was reanging my text and making hard ill add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clean method to do this would be using CSS classes. In your HTML, add a class to the css elements that should have the green background.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="green-on-hover">my link</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.green-on-hover:hover {
    background-color : green;
}
```

Note: The class name, is just like a variable-name can be anything, even 'hyphens' are allowed in the class-name. I gave 'green-on-hover' you can call it anything you want.
Found this very simple tutorial to help you with classes:
http://www.tizag.com/cssT/class.php

Hope that helped. Let me know if you have questions.

One Suggestion: Try to make your question, more generic next time.

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to this site thanks. I thought it would be classes. I just don't know how to place the a:hover and a:visited though. Things like that, where do I put that? I don't put it in those parenthasis under the class green-on-hover, right?

Comment: Just add class="green-on-hover" to every a-link you need the green background for, as I've shown in my answer. Then, in your CSS change all the interfering a:hover and a:visited to a.green-on-hover:hover and a.green-on-hover:visited.

Comment: Omg Rakesh Gopal. Thank you. I didn't notice that you said "a.green-on-hover:hover". I didn't read that exactly. That's exactly what i needed. I thought that it would be a class or id... But that's what i was trying to say but i didn't even know what i needed exactly. I didnt know you could apply a class to the a:hover thing i don't know what it's called. What's it called? But you answered my question. Thanks to the other guy too that helped also. I should've known. -.-

Answer (score 0):

You background the anchor with green and you put inside the image on it and you see the result of yours.

try this

```
html:
<a href="/index.html">
  <img width="250" height="75" class="logo" src="/victoria/logo.jpg">
  <span></span>
</a>
```

css:

```
a,a:link, a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 120px;
}
a span{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#98bf21;
  z-index:2;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
a img{
 position:relative;
 z-index:0;
}
```